# Using Math.log in Android

Tags: java, android, logarithm

I'm trying to do the calculation of this formula,

```
i = (495 / (1.0324 - 0.19077 * (Math.log(76.2 - 25.4)) + 0.15456 * (Math.log(170.18))) - 450);
```

Instead of giving the correct answer which is 20.6, its showing the wrong answer 9.59!

Then i discovered that the Math.log function is giving wrong output! How to calculate such kinda operation in Android?

Comment: The problem is not `Math.log`. What is the original expression you want to calculate ?

Comment: How did you reach the conclusion `Math.log` is the problem?  (And what number do you want as the base of your logarithm?  That might be the issue.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want to use the logarithm in [base 10](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#log10%28double%29), the one you use returns the closest double approximation of the **natural** logarithm.

So your expression should be :

```
i = (495 / (1.0324 - 0.19077 * (Math.log10(76.2 - 25.4)) + 0.15456 * (Math.log10(170.18))) - 450);
```

Output :

```
20.630024173730078
```

Comment: Yea, I even tried to add a lot of brackets to test it. log10 this is correct answer 

  i = ((495 / (1.0324 - (0.19077 * (Math.log10(76.2 - 25.4))) + (0.15456 * (Math.log10(170.18))))) - 450);

Comment: ok that actually works but didn't understand why should i use log10? because in general it should work without the log10! @ZouZou

Comment: @user3020796 That's mathematics, not programming. The result you want to calculate should use the logarithm in base 10. Even if you think that when you're doing log(5), the log is in base 10 as your default base, that's not the case in general (you take the natural one). Then just program this with the right method of the API.

Answer (score 3):

Javadoc of `Math.log`: Returns the natural logarithm (base e) of a double value.

Javadoc of `Math.log10`: Returns the base 10 logarithm of a double value.